# Context Deadline Exceeded Error - Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

I have configured apache_exporter in my web servers to expose metrics and Prometheus will **scrape** the metrics from it. It's working in all servers except public server in which apache http authentication is enabled (AuthType). How can i **scrape** using prometheus, if http authentication is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Prometheus server to use basic auth when scraping a HTTP endpoint.

See [this example config snippet](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/release-2.17/config/testdata/conf.good.yml#L85-L87) for how to use the `basic_auth` directive to configure the username and password.